# How to remove "duplicate" edges in 2-D array in Numpy?

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, graph, vectorization

I'm working with a (15000, 2) array in Numpy from which I plan to build an adjacency matrix. Each row represents a vertex connection from node to i to j, or in other words, the first element of each row has an edge with the second element. For example, [24, 79] represents an edge between node 24 and 79.

If there exists a row that was [79, 24], I would like to remove it altogether because [24, 79] already exists.

Is there a way to remove these "duplicate" connections so that the overall array only consists of uni-directional vertices? I'm doing this step before I make symmetrize the matrix, where I add the matrix to its transpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by sorting the items in each row so to easily track duplicate edges (ie. duplicate rows). The later can be done using `np.unique`. Here is an example:

```py
v = np.random.randint(0, 1_000, size=(15000, 2))  # len: 15000
result = np.unique(np.sort(v, axis=1), axis=0)    # len: 14790
```

`result` contains the set of unique non-directed edges where, for each row, the smallest ID is the first item. The computation is done efficiently in `O(n log n)` time.

Note the parameter `return_index` and `return_inverse` of `np.unique` can be used to track the unsorted row source index. Also note that using a `(2, 15_000)` array is likely to be faster due to the operation being more SIMD-friendly and cache-friendly.